# Android TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY z order control

Tags: android, accessibilityservice, accessibility

I am building an application that makes use of TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY to display some draw over windows. I noticed that if there is another application that uses the TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY, sometimes their windows are drawn on top of my windows. From what I understand the layer order (z-order) is decided based on the order that the user granted the Accessibility Permission. Is there any way to control the layers so I can set my layer on top of any other layers?

Here is a partial code to show how I display my view.

```
layoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                realScreenHeight,
                LAYOUT_FLAG,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE |
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN|
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        layoutParams.gravity =  Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;

        windowManager.addView(view, layoutParams);
```

From reading the Android source code, there is a function

```
 /**
 * Sets the layer which determines the Z-order of the window. Windows
 * with greater layer appear on top of windows with a lesser layer.
 *
 * @param layer The window layer.
 *
 * @hide
 */
public void setLayer(int layer) {
    mLayer = layer;
}
```

in `public final class AccessibilityWindowInfo` but when I try to access this function, it says that the function doesn`t exist. But the

```
 /**
     * Gets the layer which determines the Z-order of the window. Windows
     * with greater layer appear on top of windows with a lesser layer.
     *
     * @return The window layer.
     */
    public int getLayer() {
        return mLayer;
    }
```

from the same class exists and sure enough, it returns a higher number for programs that display stuff with TYPE_ACCESSIBILITY_OVERLAY if their Accessibility Permission was turned on before my Accessibility Permission.

Is there any way to control these layers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry - the ordering of these layers is undefined, and remains undefined in Android R.